# iOS animation presentationLayer hitTest does not seem to work as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, calayer

I'm trying to add touch events to small view blocks drifting from screen right side to left side. The problem is `layer.presentationLayer hitTest:point` method returns nothing, even if I do actually tap within the bounds of the view block.

Finally, I find a workaround. But, two questions still confuse me.

1. The converted point does not seem to be right, how to properly use `presentationLayer hitTest`?
2. In my code snippet, `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` is not set, why I can handle touch event anyway?

The following are the code, any help will be appreciated

#### `viewDidLoad`

```
CGRect bounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {

    ViewBlock *view = [[ViewBlock alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(bounds.size.width, 200, 40, 40)];
    [self.view addSubview:view];


    [UIView animateWithDuration:20 delay:i * 21 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
        view.frame = CGRectMake(-40, 200, 40, 40);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }];
}
```

#### ViewBlock.m

```
@implementation ViewBlock
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{

    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    return self;
}

- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    CALayer *presentationLayer = self.layer.presentationLayer; //Do NOT modify presentationLayer
    if (presentationLayer) {
        CGPoint layer_point = [presentationLayer convertPoint:point fromLayer:self.layer.modelLayer];
        if ([presentationLayer hitTest:point]) {
            return self; //not worked
        }

        if ([presentationLayer hitTest:layer_point]) {
            return self; //not worked either
        }

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(presentationLayer.bounds, layer_point)) {
            return self;  //the workaround
        }
    }
    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    NSLog(@"touches began");
}

- (void)didMoveToSuperview{
    [super didMoveToSuperview];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapTouched:)]
    ;
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;

    [self addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}

- (void)tapTouched:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender{
    NSLog(@"touches gesture");
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q1: The converted point does not seem to be right, how to properly use presentationLayer hitTest?

What you are missing is the parameter of `hitTest:` should be in the coordinate system of the receiver's super layer, so the code should be:

```
CGPoint superLayerP = [presentationLayer.superlayer convertPoint:layer_point fromLayer:presentationLayer];
if ([presentationLayer hitTest:superLayerP]) {
    return self;
}
```

> Q2:In my code snippet, UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction is not set, why I can handle touch event anyway

I think you can get touch event because you override `- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` and return `self` as result, so the event will pass to it. By default(If you don't override the hitTest:withEvent: method), you won't get touch event.

If you set `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` option, you can get touch event on the view's final frame (CGRectMake(-40, 200, 40, 40)), but in this example, the final frame is off the screen, you can set it to `CGRectMake(0, 200, 40, 40)` and have a test.